# How I can bind my List to a TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, observablecollection

I want to use TableView with a List in javaFX. It work to 90%.

My problem is that if I load my data to TableView the second row I the same how the first...I think I have a problem in my foreach.

Here My Code:

```
@FXML
    private TableView<Ticket> tblTicket = new TableView<>();

...


@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        try {
               ...

                tblTicket.getColumns().addAll(Ticket.getColumn(tblTicket));

                tblTicket.setItems(getTicketData());

        } catch (Exception e) {
           ...
        }
    }    


...

public ObservableList<Ticket> getTicketData() {

        //Eine Liste mit allen Tickets
        ObservableList<Ticket> ticketData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ticketData.setAll(new Ticket("1", "Fehler 1", "Meier_A", "01.02.2015", "Offen"));
        ticketData.setAll(new Ticket("2", "Fehler 2", "Schmidt_W", "01.02.2015", "In Bearbeitung"));
        ticketData.setAll(new Ticket("3", "Fehler 3", "Tarasov_W", "01.02.2015", "Geschlossen"));

        return ticketData; 
    }

...
```

I make it how in this video but my table is empty.

Comment: Your code has errors in its implementation, probably because you misunderstand how TableView works, e.g., you don't need to create cell value factories for each ticket in a for loop.  Review the [Oracle JavaFX TableView Tutorial: Example 13-6 Creating a Table and Adding Data to It](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJABHGAJ) and [Example 13-8 Table with the Text Fields to Enter New Items](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAFABCH) - the later example would appear to be exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Example 13-8 appears to be a complete implementation of what you are trying to do.  How does it not solve your problem?  What is it about that example that you cannot understand or apply or that differs from what you are trying to do which makes it not immediately applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to set something like this in your initialize() instead of for loop and there is no need in `ticketData.size()>0`

```
public void initialize(){ //added after James_D comment about initialize()
    clmID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ticketId"));
    clmTicketName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ticketName"));
    clmLastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ticketLastName"));
    clmCategory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ticketCategory"));
    clmFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ticketFirstName"));
}
```

Edit:

**Here is demo**: 
https://github.com/varren/How-I-can-bind-my-List-to-a-TableView-in-JavaFX/tree/master/src/sample

**Here is tutorial**:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#CACFEHBI

Comment: ah, but `private void TableViewLoad` is not a constructor.

Comment: no i not have a constructor for tableView ... your solution not work :/ I get StringProberty[value: 1] in my cell

Comment: @Tarasov yep yep my bad, i meant that you can do that once somewhere  `if (!initialised) {  initialised = true;  /*setFactories Code here */}` here is demo: https://github.com/varren/How-I-can-bind-my-List-to-a-TableView-in-JavaFX/tree/master/src/sample and btw it is much easier to just add  `<TableColumn text="Last Name" >
        <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
        </cellValueFactory>
     </TableColumn>` in FXML file

Comment: This looks like a controller class, so this should go in the `initialize()` method.